# Passing checkbox value from view to controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to pass checkbox value from views to controller so that I can compare the checked/unchecked values (for database update)?

Views:

```
@foreach ($second as $sec)
    <br>
    <div class = "form-group">
        {{$sec->Roll }}
        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        {{ $sec->Name}}
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" value="{{$sec->Roll}}"  name="1" />
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Controller:

```
foreach ($columns as $col) {
    //dd("Y");
    if($col == $txt[1]) {
        $got=DB::table($req)->select($col)->get();
        //dd($got);
        //COMPARE CHECKBOX VALUE "CHECKED/UNCHECKED" WITH ITS DEFAULT VALUE 
        DB::statement("UPDATE " . $req . " set " . $got . " to " . $got . " + 1 WHERE" .$req->Roll . " IN ".( implode(',', $req)));
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the ways I have done it is not to put any value in the checkbox element. Then inspect if the value returned is string with `is_string($the_variable)` or not. This might not be an ideal solution, but a bit curious if you have tried it. Any checked checkbox would have 'on' as the value, while unchecked one would have `null` Have you also tried to inspect the values in your request?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ps: This might be applicable only if my description matches what you are trying to do, because your question seems so.

One of the ways I have done it is not to put any value in the checkbox element. Then inspect if the value returned is string with is_string($the_variable) or not. That is, instead of:

```
<input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" value="{{$sec->Roll}}"  name="checkbox_1"  />
```

I'll have:

```
 <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox"  name="checkbox_1"  />
```

This might not be an ideal solution, but a bit curious if you have tried it. 
So in the controller, any checked checkbox would have 'on' as the value, while unchecked one would have null:

so if I do in my controller:

```
return request()->all();
```

I should get the values of the checked as 'on' and the values of the unchecked as `null`

So i'll do for example in controller:

```
if(is_string(request()->get('checkbox_1))) {
    //checked
else {
    // unchecked
}
```

Hope this is clear now.

Just for an update:

One other way to do this is to pass the key of the column you are trying to update when making the foreach, so you will have something like this:

```
@foreach ($second as $key=> $sec)
```

then on the checkbox it will serve as different names:

```
<input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="{{ $key }}" />
```

This way if you do return `request()->all();` at the first in your controller, you can then tell if something else is wrong or not.

Please make sure you note the `$key` in that foreach() so to be sure you are doing the right thing.

Comment: Its only returning NULL value. :'(

Comment: @ArunimaBaidya you should check the checkbox before submitting the form, and also ensure you are calling the right parameter of the request. As you can see from the example I gave that I am calling the checkbox with the name `checkbox_1` this is very important so as to know if what you have is correct or not

Comment: well it worked !! But here am working on a whole bunch of checkboxes . It's working for just one value

Comment: @Arunima Badiya, One other way to do this is to pass the key of the column you are trying to update when making the foreach, so you will have something like this: `@foreach ($second as $key=> $sec)` then on the checkbox it will serve as different names:  `<input tabindex="1" type="checkbox"  name="{{ $key }}"  />` This way if you do `return request()->all();` at the first in your controller, you can then tell if something else is wrong or not

Comment: The problem I suppose is that all your checkboxes have only one name, i.e, '1' and that means that the behaviour you might likely have is have a null value when they are submit.